# Finding and Displaying Unique Names

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

A bit of context: I am working on a short film, which requires a lot of props and assets that need to be made. To keep track of what I need and how each asset is progressing i have made a spreadsheet.

[image]

What I am wanting to do is enter the names of the assets in a shot: Grass, Dirt, Tree, etc. Then have it automatically separate all of the names in to their own cell in a column. So, separate names, and enter them in a column, also filter them so that only unique names are entered.

I only know a bit of excel formula writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the latest version of Excel, you can use a combination of `TEXTSPLIT` and `UNIQUE` functions to get the desired result as seen on the image below.

[image]

In case you want to split a whole range, you can combine `TEXTJOIN`, `TEXTSPLIT` and `UNIQUE` functions. `TEXTJOIN` combine the cells into one, `TEXTSPLIT` divides cells into a single column, and `UNIQUE` shows unique elements.

[image]

Comment: Hello, thanks for the info, very useful. Is there a way to sample an column, say D2:D10 and have it do the same thing?

Comment: @Haggis2.0 See edit.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!

Comment: It's another question, and you will have to explain better as I am not sure I understand. You want to split and count the elements from the range? All of them or the unique ones?

Comment: I have figured it out